# Unknown CMake command "cotire".

Tags: cmake

This is my dockerfile:

```
from ubuntu:16.04
maintainer Nico Cesar <nico@nicocesar.com>

# Set the env variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y git cmake python-virtualenv python-pip

RUN git clone https://github.com/lyft/envoy.git
RUN cd envoy && make
RUN cd envoy && mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake ..
```

And I get this error

```
CMake Error at source/common/CMakeLists.txt:141 (cotire):
   Unknown CMake command "cotire".
```

How do I add a command to CMake? this is taken from the envoy github.

They claim that ubuntu14 will work, but g++ is too old, and ubuntu16 has this missing cotire that I'm unfamiliar with, any idea how to add it?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sakra/cotire/blob/master/MANUAL.md) is guide on how to "install" (it's just one file) and use cotire.

Comment: Let me re-emphasize that cotire is currently not part of the official CMake distribution. So if you want to use it, you always have to install it manually in addition to the stock CMake.

Answer (score 2):

`cotire` is a [cmake module on github](https://github.com/sakra/cotire) that automates the process of creating precompiled headers for your implementation files in a cross-platform way. The github project has a bunch of fluff files, but the only file you really need is located at CMake/cotire.cmake. If this file is present in CMake's module search path, your build should continue as normal.